# Replace forward slash with a sequence of back and forward slash

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace a sequence of forward slash such as '//' with '\/'.
For example: 'http://www.test.com/' should return  'http:\/\/www.test.com\/'
I have tried a few commands in python such as the examples below, but haven't been successful yet:

`myString.replace(r'/',r'\\/')` returns `'http:\\\\/\\\\/www.test.com.br\\\\/'`

`myString.replace(r'/','\\\/')` also returns `'http:\\\\/\\\\/www.test.com.br\\\\/'`

How can I obtain the result that I need?

I am using Python 3.8

Comment: Why are you using a raw string and then still escaping the backslash? Also, you are confusing the repr of your string (meaning, what you'd need to type in to produce that string) with what the string actually contains.

Comment: It was because when I saw how my question would appear to the viewers in the editor, it showed less slashs than what I had actually typed, so I ended up adding more to correct that. However, when my question was posted my code was interpreted and the extra slashes were actually not necessary

Answer (score 1):

When you use a raw string, the backslash is no longer used as an escape character, and everything shows up in the string just as you typed it (you still can't end a string with a backslash, though). You only need to double it up if you're not using raw strings. Also, the result you saw was directly returned in an interactive session, which means you saw the `repr` of that string - meaning, it's telling you what you'd need to type in to produce the same object. Don't overdo it with raw strings and backslashes, and use `print`.

```
>>> myString = 'http://www.test.com/'
>>> print(mystring.replace('/', r'\/'))
http:\/\/www.test.com\/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it to me!